# Higher derived cokernels

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Assuming there is a (not necessarily object-wise injective) natural transformation $\eta:1\Rightarrow F$ where $F$ is an exact functor (in fact $\eta$ is the adjunction morphism and $F$ the composition of some two biadjoint functor, but I don't know whether this is necessary). I can consider the cokernel of $\eta$, i. e. $C: M\mapsto\operatorname{coker}(M\rightarrow FM)$, which is right exact and hence admits a left derived functor $L^iC$.

Should I expect $L^iC$ to vanish for $i>1$?

Why it should: I thought the derived functor was given by $L^i CM = H^i\operatorname{cone}(M\rightarrow FM)[-1]$, and hence should only have homology in degrees 0 and 1.

Comment: What is $F$?$\text{}$

Comment: @JeremyRickard Sorry; I have added that $F$ is assumed to be exact, otherwise $C$ needs not to be right exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the assumption that $\eta$ is the unit of an adjunction, this certainly may not be true.

For example, let $F$ be the identity functor on the module category of a commutative ring $R$, and let $\eta$ be the natural transformation given by multiplication by $x$ for some $x\in R$. Then $C$ is the functor $-\otimes_RR/xR$. But $\text{Tor}^R_i(-,R/xR)$ can be non-zero for all $i$ (e.g., $R=\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2)$ and $x=t$).

Comment: Okay, but now I cannot see why this could not happen if $\eta$ was some adjunction unit.

Comment: @Bubaya When I wrote that it can be false without that assumption, I didn't mean to imply that it must be true with the assumption. I don't know whether that's the case or not.